# How to get data once on WordPress page template and access it across multiple shortcodes that are used in same page

Tags: wordpress, templates

Have a requirement to create a WordPress dynamically based on multiple apis data, And we want to use that response data chunks as short code in page builder while designing backed with template.

We want to retrieve data only once in page template and how to make it available something $post without having to fetch on each short code.

Ex: $system_data -> which might contain name, description, performance etc, more attributes
And want to make common short code which takes attribute and get the relevant information.

[system-data attr="performance"]

What is the best way to achieve this, without loading whole data on each short code

Answer (score 0):

you can use global variable to store data from first short code and use in other short code for entire page but you should check value is empty or not in every short code before use it